# Wired connection with switch/router in between becomes really slow

Tags: networking, router, switch

So I have my ISP with contract download speed of 500Mbps and upload speed of 100Mbps.

I've connected a Cat6 cable from the original ISP router to my office area (around 25m).
If I connect the cable directly to my desktop I can get the desired speeds.

I also want to have WiFi in the area so I did the following things:

- First I've connected the ISP router to an Asus Router (RT-AC1200G+). I then connected the router to my PC (once again, another Cat6 cable). Doing speed test I never go over 95/98 Mbps download speed. I've also tried with another (cheaper) router and same thing happens.
- Today I've connected the ISP router to a Gigabit switch. I then connected the switch to my PC and speed test showing the exact same thing 95/98 Mbps download speed.

Also, on each approach, I also get the same 95/98Mbps download speed on Wifi.

What can be causing this? I'm using all Cat6 cables and I've even replaced then just to make sure they were ok.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you make the cables yourself? Have you checked for a "split pair"?

Comment: First connect a laptop to the ISP router directly and run a speed test - if that doesn't give the speed you expect, its time to call customer support and complain until they fix it.

Comment: So I had cables I've done myself and some ones I've bought. Basically the cables I had to connect from switch to PC (3 of them to be exact) where not ok. Eventually I got a new one and it started working